# Jquery not ready with $(window).on("load", function() {{}})

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my template and it keeps coming back as `$ is not defined` in the console.   However, if I wrap it in a setTimeout of a 500ms, it works fine.  Is there a way to wait for Jquery to load without erroring?

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  console.log("TEST")
});
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before your window.load code?

Comment: @j08691 yea, the template is a PHP Blade file.  Jquery is loaded in from the layout level so it's available on every template

Comment: Is jQuery being loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @herkypam yes, that we assume, but where in the blade template is the code above and where is your jQuery library included? (maybe if you show us the blade template, things get more clear)

Answer (score -1):

That's because you don't have jquery, try adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your page.

You can see the generated source code in your browser `ctrl + U` and see if jquery is added or not, or with the dev tools

Comment: Please consider OP's comments on the question before submitting an answer. While there may be an issue with the manner in which they're loading jQuery, OP has said *"Jquery is loaded in from the layout level so it's available on every template"*. They've also said that a simple half-second timeout resolves the issue, so jQuery is being loaded *at some point*.